# Windows 7 strange boot issue

Tags: windows-7, windows

Recently I installed an SSD drive, its now my primary boot drive (OCZ Vertex Turbo 60GB). 
I'm running Win 7 (64bit).

Now I am not sure exactly where the fault lies, but when I do a restart from within Windows, the computer will boot and enter into the loading windows portion, however won't progress beyond there.

My solution is to manually hit the reset switch, and then when it boots it enters into a windows menu that offers a start up repair or start windows normally. I select start windows normally, and then it boots fine.

I am not entirely sure why I can't just restart the computer from windows normally though.

The SSD drive works perfectly, and not even sure if it is the cause to this problem.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: try forcing windows to boot normal way using BCDEDIT ? not sure about the exact command for that

Comment: Strange. Just for the record, I'm booting Windows 64 bit (RTM) on an OCZ Vertex 120 (not the newer Turbo model) and never had this issue. I usually sleep, but of course have to restart sometimes for software installs, updates and the like.
Have you checked if there is a flash update for your drive? (which would unfortunately necessitate a complete reinstall too)

Comment: If you shut down completely and then hit the power button does it work normally or does the same thing happen? Is it only with a restart that it has this problem?

Comment: I suggest you do some reading on the OCZ forums about firmware and running Windows on that Model Drive

http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?233-OCZ-Flash-Support-And-Discussion-Forum